# md-date-picker date format issue with date format

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I have this problem.
Here is my datepicker

```
<md-datepicker class="form-control" ng-model="startDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
```

The point is that when I select a date, for example the 23rd of September, instead to see 23/11/2017 I see 11/23/2017. So there is a way to specify my date format as dd/MM/yyyy?
I tried using ng-model-options attribute but no success.
Thanks.

Comment: Solved it. I needed to import the $mdDateLocaleProvider service and the moment.js file. Then on my module, specify the config

.config([''$mdDateLocaleProvider',
        function($mdDateLocaleProvider) {

         $mdDateLocaleProvider.formatDate = function(date) {
             var m = moment( date );
          return m.isValid() ? m.format( 'DD/MM/YYYY' ) : '';
         };